# how to run my webapplication on the server ASP.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-3.5

I have created a web application using Visualstudio 2008 using C# on my computer.

I am using windows server 2003.

I have now published the webapplication and put those contents in the server.. with a field called inetpub\wwwroot.

i have created a root directory for it in the IIS with the name "super".

Now i need to see this in internetexplorer how do i do this...

I am new to this so please help me..

Thanks

Is there a Procedure on how to do all this from the start...

Comment: Exactly how did you publish the web site? Did you right-click the project and use the Publish command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a .net website or .net web application, you can follow these instructions on [Deploying ASP.NET Applications in IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2f45f2ea-bcf8-4d23-9f15-5caf7ebdc2ef.mspx?mfr=true). In overview, when you do a publish from visual studio, you're compiling the application down to it's assemblies, you're stripping out the code behind files, and only moving over what is needed to run the site/application. Your webserver should be setup with a virtual directory pointing to the published folder, and it would be a good idea to have a Default.aspx page in the folder since the webserver looks for this page as it's starting point. Usually the default website is the site used inside of IIS for websites (at least when you've only got one). You should be able to right click on a file and browse the file if you have followed all of the setup instructions found in the referenced link.

Good luck, and hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Within IIS, you could right click on default.asp and select browse.

Comment: So, select Webform3.aspx and select browse.

Comment: @unknown, i'm not fully clear what you did.  what do you mean you created a root directory?  did you create a web app in iis?